# What do I look for to show that a curve has a self intersection?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curves

I am looking at the following question

Consider $f(x,y,z) = (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}-r)^2 + z^2 - a^2$ the zero set of this gives a torus. The torus has an interior hole of radius $1$ and rotating circle of radius $1, (a=1, r=2)$. Then consider a curve $z(t) = (t, m\cdot t)$ so that $x(z(t))$ is a curve on the torus,

-Prove that this curve on the torus has a self-intersection if and only if the number m is a rational number.

What do I need to show to demonstrate the curve has a self intersection? To me it seems that the curve would have the same value at two different places. So, there is some rational number m that when plugged into $x(z(t))$ will have the same value at different times?

I have found $x(u,v)$ to be $((r+acosv)cosu, (r+acosv)sinu, asinv)$

Any advice on how to show this?

Comment: What does the curve $z(t)=(t,mt)$ have to do with your equation of the torus? By the way, you forgot to make it an equation.

Comment: Fixed it if you made the edit suggestions. I am not exactly sure what you mean, the problem only tells me that z(t) = (t,mt) is a curve such that x(z(t)) is on the torus. The equation I have for the torus does not have any m's or t's. But it does have the z-component and a z. @TedShifrin

Comment: What is $x(u,v)$? This is *not* the equation you've written down. And it's still not an equation. Your torus is given by $f(x,y,z)=0$, but they are referring to a parametrization of this torus by *two* variables.

Comment: My latex is not very good, so I will try to write this to the best of my ability. I have it as ((r+acosv)cosu, (r+acosv)sinu, asinv) @tedshifrin

Comment: You need to include that detail in the question, not the comment section. You also need to set $f=0$, at the moment it is not describing anything.

Comment: Yeah this torus was described in our last homework where we actually found x(theta, phi). I have edited the question to fix both the description of the torus and to include this parameterization.

Comment: I have now edited, and I am still stuck. Any advice?

Comment: **HINT**: What leaps out at you about the trig functions?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry for the late reply, had an exam this week and got caught up working on that. I am not exactlty sure of what you are implying about the trig functions. I am not going to have anything like $cos^2$ or $sin^2$. One hint I was given was to set the components of the parameterization equal to each other and by using something like x(z(t0) = x(z(t1)) (this is true if it has a self intersection) that I could then use all three to show that m had to be rational, but I am not sure what that looks like. I have u and v on both sides, so not too sure where I would plug t0 and t1 in at

Comment: I'm suggesting that you think about the fact that the trig functions are periodic!

Comment: Is that because in the definition of periodic functions explains that they repeat their values in regular intervals? So for example if U, V = 0 we would have components ((r+a), 0, 0) and then at U,V = 2pi we would have the same components at different values of u and v? That does make sense, but I am trying to show that for $z = (t, m*t)$ the curve $x(z(t))$ has a self intersection iff m is rational.

Comment: Is the z = (t,m*t) showing different values for u and v? What I mean is, for example  does u = t and v = mt and then I show that there curve only has the same values if v is some rational multiple of u?

Comment: Is that what you are referring to @tedshifrin?

Comment: Try a specific value for $m$ and look at the equations.

Comment: My issue is that I am not sure what the equations shoud look like? Do I let $u = t$ and $v = m*t$ inside my paramteriaztion when setting those components equal to each other? So like $(r+acos(t0))cos(m*t0) = (r+acos(t1))cos(m*t1)$? @TedShifrin